# I have installed new icons in my ubuntu 18 now I can't open many of my applications including gnome tweaks

Tags: icon-themes, gnome-tweaks

I have installed new icons in my ubuntu 18 now I can't open many of my applications including gnome tweaks, this is the error:

```
(gnome-tweaks:8688): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:34:24.347: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:7852:22: Expected '(' after 'url'

(gnome-tweaks:8688): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:34:24.347: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:7852:147: Invalid character in string. Must be escaped.

(gnome-tweaks:8688): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:34:24.352: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:11634:3: '/*' in comment block

(gnome-tweaks:8688): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:34:24.352: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:11740:2: '/*' in comment block

(gnome-tweaks:8688): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:34:24.352: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:11785:26: 'text-shadow' is not a valid color name

(gnome-tweaks:8688): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:34:24.352: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:12045:14: 'ffffff' is not a valid color name

(gnome-tweaks:8688): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:34:24.566: Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
**
Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /home/cap10n3mo/.icons/Mac-moD-master/mimes/48/image.svg: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Chances are the theme change was only applied for your user. Try creating a temporary user account, logging in, and see if it appears correctly. The local user theme can also be specified in the `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` file, so if you can't change it from Gnome Tweaks, you may be able to edit this file to change it.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  There's an 18.04 and an 18.10, but no 18 in Ubuntu. Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Your icon theme is not compatible with the current GTK Version. Replace it with one that works.